# Formatting of badges is not proper - a possible bug?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, badges

Today while searching for badges I found that some of the badges specially with long name aren't formatted rightly. For example-

[image]

Another example-

[image]

One more example where description of tag is about to go out-

[image]

And a last one -

[image]

As you can see searching of badges give the badge but not with proper styling. In some the name is going out of the box. In some description is going out of box. In some a lot of space is being taken for adjustment. Is there some issue with styling? A possible bug? Then please if possible please do the styling normal or is it related to that my device size is far from normal so that is why not proper styling?

Comment: Have you tried it on a different browser? It works fine on my [device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCccd.png).

Comment: @Wolgwang in mine laptop in both in chrome and edge the bug is coming

Comment: [Dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367433/842411) on main meta.

Comment: @Wolgwang oh I didin't knew it is asked on meta too. Btw idk how this works in your device